# Блеск у блоков меню на сайте, интересно как получить такой эффект

Tags: html, css

http://for-mma.ru/

В главном меню сайта отображается интересный эффект, кто нибудь может подскажет с помощью чего он был реализован, неужели это только HTML и CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Пример использует не только HTML и CSS, но ещё и JavaScript.

Напишу пример на jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ // При загрузке страницы..
  let linkW = $('.nav a').eq(0).outerWidth(), // Получаем ширину первой ссылки
      linkX = $('.nav a').eq(0).position().left; // позицию left первой ссылки
  $('.nav .effect').css({ // устанавлием блок .effect следующие свойства:
    'width': linkW, // такую же ширину как у ссылки
    'left': linkX, // и такую же позицию left
    'visibility': 'visible' // "включаем" отображение
  });
});

$('.nav a').hover(function(){ // При каждом наведение на ссылку..
  let linkW = $(this).outerWidth(), // получаем ширину той ссылки на которую наведён курсор
      linkX = $(this).position().left; // и позицию left этой же ссылки
  $('.nav .effect').css({ // далее устанавливаем .effect следующие свойства
    'width': linkW, // такую же ширину
    'left': linkX // и позицию left, в общем всё как в прошлый раз.
  }); 
});
```

```css
.nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.nav::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.nav > a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav > a, .effect {
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.effect {
  display: block;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiMyg.png') no-repeat center center / auto 120%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all linear .2s;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav">
  <a href="#">Link One</a>
  <a href="#">Link Two</a>
  <a href="#">Link Three</a>
  <a href="#">Link Four</a>
  <a href="#">Link Five</a>
  <a href="#">Link Six</a>
  <div class="effect"></div>
</div>
```